# Can't issue Get log page, identifier Log Identifier(LID) = 5 in windows

Tags: winapi, windows-10, nvme

I use following code to issue command in windows 10

```
ZeroMemory(buffer, bufferLength);

query = (PSTORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY)buffer;
protocolDataDescr = (PSTORAGE_PROTOCOL_DATA_DESCRIPTOR)buffer;
protocolData = (PSTORAGE_PROTOCOL_SPECIFIC_DATA)query->AdditionalParameters;

query->PropertyId = StorageAdapterProtocolSpecificProperty;
query->QueryType = PropertyStandardQuery;

protocolData->ProtocolType = ProtocolTypeNvme;
protocolData->DataType = NVMeDataTypeLogPage;
protocolData->ProtocolDataRequestValue = lid;
protocolData->ProtocolDataRequestSubValue = 0;

result = DeviceIoControl(FileHandle,
    IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY,
    buffer,
    bufferLength,
    buffer,
    bufferLength,
    &returnedLength,
    NULL);
```

case 1 :Get log page use lid(1~3) that device can received - OK
case 2 :Get log page lid=5 (Command Supported and Effects) that device can't received anything. - failed
case 3 :use linux api can received by device.(Get log page 1~5)
Case 1 and Case 2, GetLastError() = 0 (SUCCESS)

what is the problem with case 2?

How can i issue Get log page(lid = 5 (Command Supported and Effects)) correctly in windows 10?

Comment: Can show the full code so that i can reproduce it? And you can use `GetLastError()` to check what error code DeviceIoControl returned.

Comment: My final purpose is to issue vuc command by windows host and receive by device.
I found the solution by myself.
Windows need to receive get log page with corresponding vuc command.
Windows will issue get log page in Linkup, can't not issue get log page(lid =5) by DeviceIOCtrl

Comment: Glad to hear that. You can post your solution. It's kind of you that there will be a guidance to others.